# View.OnClickListener doen't get triggered in activity

Tags: android, android-activity, interface, android-event

I have an Activity which implements `View.OnClickListener` along with several other abstract methods form different classes.  The problem is that the global `onClick` does not get triggered.

I have to set a new OnClickListener for every individual view manually and I can not find where in my code the click event gets consumed and is prevented from propagating to `onClick(View view)` method.

Here is the body of my activity:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.R;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.util.ApiResponse;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.util.Cache;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.util.CustomToast;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.util.Feed;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.util.MultipartUtility;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.util.ProfilesSingleton;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.util.Util;
import com.imnumbers.imnumbers.widget.ObservableScrollView;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class FeedsActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener, NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, NavigationDrawerFragmentRight.NavigationDrawerCallbacks,
        ObservableScrollView.Callbacks, FeedsHeadFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final int STATE_ONSCREEN = 0;
    private int mState = STATE_ONSCREEN;
    private static final int STATE_OFFSCREEN = 1;
    private static final int STATE_RETURNING = 2;
    private final int PANEL_STATUS_OPEN = 1;
    private final int PANEL_STATUS_CLOSED = 0;
    private int morePanelStatus = PANEL_STATUS_CLOSED;
    AQuery aq;
    String last_time_modified = "0";
    boolean getting_feeds = false;
    boolean first_time = true;
    ArrayList<Feed> feeds;
    @InjectView(R.id.feedLoader)
    ProgressBar feedLoader;
    @InjectView(R.id.feedsListView)
    LinearLayout feedContainer;
    @InjectView(R.id.pullToRWrapper)
    LinearLayout pullToRWrapper;
    @InjectView(R.id.pullToRText)
    TextView pullToRText;
    @InjectView(R.id.retryBtn)
    TextView retryBtn;
    @InjectView(R.id.menuLayout)
    LinearLayout menuBtn;
    @InjectView(R.id.moreBtn)
    ImageView moreBtn;
    @InjectView(R.id.morePanel)
    RelativeLayout morePanel;
    @InjectView(R.id.changeCoverWrapper)
    LinearLayout changeCoverWrapper;
    @InjectView(R.id.changeProfilePhotoWrapper)
    LinearLayout changeProfilePhotoWrapper;
    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private NavigationDrawerFragmentRight mNavigationDrawerFragmentRight;
    private ObservableScrollView mObservableScrollView;
    private RelativeLayout mQuickReturnView;
    private View mPlaceholderView;
    private ScrollSettleHandler mScrollSettleHandler = new ScrollSettleHandler();
    private int mMinRawY = 0;
    private int mQuickReturnHeight;
    private int mMaxScrollY;
    private Context c;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private float lastY;
    private int Y;
    private boolean refresh = false;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feeds);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        c = this;
        aq = new AQuery(c);
        feeds = new ArrayList<Feed>();
        last_time_modified = "0";
        first_time = true;
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        // Navigation Drawers
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawerFragmentRight = (NavigationDrawerFragmentRight)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer_right);
        mTitle = getTitle();
        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        mNavigationDrawerFragmentRight.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer_right,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        // End - Navigation Drawers

        mObservableScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.oscrollview);
        mObservableScrollView.setCallbacks(this);

        mQuickReturnView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.head);
        mPlaceholderView = findViewById(R.id.place_holder);

        mObservableScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        onScrollChanged(mObservableScrollView.getScrollY());
                        mMaxScrollY = mObservableScrollView.computeVerticalScrollRange()
                                - mObservableScrollView.getHeight();
                        mQuickReturnHeight = mQuickReturnView.getHeight();
                    }
                });
        setOnClicks();

        ViewHelper.setScaleX(morePanel, 2);
        ViewHelper.setScaleY(morePanel, 2);
        ViewHelper.setAlpha(morePanel, 0);


        if (!Util.isNetworkAvailable(c)) {
            CustomToast.makeToast(c, CustomToast.TYPE_ALERT, c.getString(R.string.no_internet_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        new GetFeedsAsyncTask(ProfilesSingleton.getInstance().getCurrentProfile().getProfileID(), 0).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feeds, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY) {
        scrollY = Math.min(mMaxScrollY, scrollY);

        mScrollSettleHandler.onScroll(scrollY);

        int rawY = mPlaceholderView.getTop() - scrollY;
        int translationY = 0;

        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_OFFSCREEN:
                if (rawY <= mMinRawY) {
                    mMinRawY = rawY;
                } else {
                    mState = STATE_RETURNING;
                }
                translationY = rawY;
                break;

            case STATE_ONSCREEN:
                if (rawY < -mQuickReturnHeight) {
                    mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                    mMinRawY = rawY;
                }
                translationY = rawY;
                break;

            case STATE_RETURNING:
                translationY = (rawY - mMinRawY) - mQuickReturnHeight;
                if (translationY > 0) {
                    translationY = 0;
                    mMinRawY = rawY - mQuickReturnHeight;
                }

                if (rawY > 0) {
                    mState = STATE_ONSCREEN;
                    translationY = rawY;
                }

                if (translationY < -mQuickReturnHeight) {
                    mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                    mMinRawY = rawY;
                }
                break;
        }
        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(mQuickReturnView).cancel();
        ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mQuickReturnView, translationY + scrollY);
        Y = scrollY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownMotionEvent() {
        mScrollSettleHandler.setSettleEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent() {
        mScrollSettleHandler.setSettleEnabled(true);
        mScrollSettleHandler.onScroll(mObservableScrollView.getScrollY());
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    public JSONArray getFeeds(boolean forceRefresh, int profileID, int lastFeedTime) throws IOException, JSONException {
        if (!forceRefresh || !Util.isNetworkAvailable(c)) {

            String cache = Cache.readFromCache(c, "feeds");
            if (!cache.equals("")) {
                try {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(cache);
                    return ja;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        getting_feeds = true;

        JSONArray feedsArray = null;
        try {
            MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(Util.URL_GET_FEEDS, "UTF-8");

            multipart.addFormField("profile_id",
                    String.valueOf(profileID));
            List<String> response = multipart.finish();
            ApiResponse responseObject = new ApiResponse(response.get(0));
            if (responseObject.isSuccessful()) {
                feedsArray = responseObject.getDataJSONArray();
            } else {
                CustomToast.makeToast(c, CustomToast.TYPE_ALERT, c.getString(R.string.unknown_error), CustomToast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



        return feedsArray;
    }

    private void showFeeds(final JSONArray array) {
        feedLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        feedContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        feedContainer.removeAllViews();

        //if (first_time) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View feedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_layout, feedContainer, false);
            final Feed feed;
            try {
                feed = new Feed(array.getJSONObject(i));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            final int position = i;
            @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") CircleImageView avatar = (CircleImageView) feedView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            aq.id(avatar).image(feed.getProfile().getPhotoFullPath(), false, true, 50, R.drawable.avatar);

            TextView username = (TextView) feedView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            final Feed finalFeed = feed;
            username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent profile = new Intent(c, SingleProfileActivity.class);
                    int profileID = finalFeed.getProfile().getProfileID();
                    profile.putExtra("profile_id", profileID);
                    startActivity(profile);
                }
            });
            TextView date = (TextView) feedView.findViewById(R.id.feed_date);
            ViewStub feedContent = (ViewStub) feedView.findViewById(R.id.feed_content);
            View content;
            switch (feed.getType()) {
                case "photo":
                    feedContent.setLayoutResource(R.layout.feed_content_photo);
                    content = feedContent.inflate();
                    ImageView feedPhoto = (ImageView) content.findViewById(R.id.feed_pic);
                    aq.id(feedPhoto).image(Util.URL_FEEDS_PHOTOS + feed.getPhotoPath(), false, true, 0, 0, null, 0, AQuery.RATIO_PRESERVE);
                    break;
                default:
                case "simple":
                    feedContent.setLayoutResource(R.layout.feed_content_simple);
                    content = feedContent.inflate();
                    break;
                case "aparat":
                case "music":
                    continue;
            }
            RelativeLayout commentsWrapper = (RelativeLayout) feedView.findViewById(R.id.feed_comments);
            commentsWrapper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int pos = position;
                    Intent singleFeedActivity = new Intent(c, SingleFeedActivity.class);
                    singleFeedActivity.putExtra("feed_position", pos);
                    singleFeedActivity.putExtra("feeds", array.toString());
                    startActivity(singleFeedActivity);
                }
            });
            TextView feed_text = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.feed_text);
            username.setText(feed.getProfile().getFirstName() + " " + feed.getProfile().getLastName());
            date.setText(String.valueOf(feed.getTimeCreated()));
            feed_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(feed.getText()));
            ((TextView) feedView.findViewById(R.id.likesCountText)).setText(String.valueOf(feed.getLikesCount()));
            feedContainer.addView(feedView);
        }

        if (feedContainer.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            feedContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        getting_feeds = false;
    }

    public void goToPostActivity(View view) {
        Intent postActivity = new Intent(this, PostFeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(postActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
//        CustomToast.makeToast(c, CustomToast.TYPE_DEFAULT, "refreshing", CustomToast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.d("Refresh", "Doing Refresh!");
        new GetFeedsAsyncTask(ProfilesSingleton.getInstance().getCurrentProfile().getProfileID(), 0).execute();
    }

    public void setOnClicks() {
        menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).openDrawer(mNavigationDrawerFragment.getView());
            }
        });
        moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (morePanelStatus) {
                    case PANEL_STATUS_OPEN:
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(morePanel).scaleX(1);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(morePanel).scaleY(1);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(morePanel).alpha(1);

/*                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeCoverWrapper).scaleX(1);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeCoverWrapper).scaleY(1);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeCoverWrapper).alpha(1);

                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeProfilePhotoWrapper).scaleX(1);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeProfilePhotoWrapper).scaleY(1);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeProfilePhotoWrapper).alpha(1);*/
                        morePanelStatus = PANEL_STATUS_CLOSED;
                        break;
                    case PANEL_STATUS_CLOSED:
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(morePanel).scaleX(2);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(morePanel).scaleY(2);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(morePanel).alpha(0);

/*                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeCoverWrapper).scaleX(3);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeCoverWrapper).scaleY(3);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeCoverWrapper).alpha(0);

                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeProfilePhotoWrapper).scaleX(3);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeProfilePhotoWrapper).scaleY(3);
                        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(changeProfilePhotoWrapper).alpha(0);*/
                        morePanelStatus = PANEL_STATUS_OPEN;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        retryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new GetFeedsAsyncTask(ProfilesSingleton.getInstance().getCurrentProfile().getProfileID(), 0).execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("Global Click", "click"+ view.getId());
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feeds, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }

    }

    private class ScrollSettleHandler extends Handler {
        private static final int SETTLE_DELAY_MILLIS = 100;

        private int mSettledScrollY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        private boolean mSettleEnabled;

        public void onScroll(int scrollY) {
            if (mSettledScrollY != scrollY) {
                // Clear any pending messages and post delayed
                removeMessages(0);
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, SETTLE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                mSettledScrollY = scrollY;
            }
        }

        public void setSettleEnabled(boolean settleEnabled) {
            mSettleEnabled = settleEnabled;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Handle the scroll settling.
            if (STATE_RETURNING == mState && mSettleEnabled) {
                int mDestTranslationY;
                if (mSettledScrollY - ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mQuickReturnView) > mQuickReturnHeight / 2) {
                    mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                    mDestTranslationY = Math.max(
                            mSettledScrollY - mQuickReturnHeight,
                            mPlaceholderView.getTop());
                } else {
                    mDestTranslationY = mSettledScrollY;
                }

                mMinRawY = mPlaceholderView.getTop() - mQuickReturnHeight - mDestTranslationY;
                ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(mQuickReturnView).translationY(mDestTranslationY);
            }
            mSettledScrollY = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // reset
        }
    }

    public class GetFeedsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        int profileID, lastFeedTime;
        JSONArray feedsArray;

        public GetFeedsAsyncTask(int profileID, int lastFeedTime) {
            this.profileID = profileID;
            this.lastFeedTime = lastFeedTime;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                feedsArray = getFeeds(true, profileID, lastFeedTime);
                return 1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer param) {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            if (param == 1) {
                showFeeds(feedsArray);
                feedLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

            }
            //super.onPostExecute(param);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            feedLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did u mention yourView.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Yes you should mention yourView.setonClickListener(this) in OnCreate.

Comment: @Softcoder what do you mean?

Comment: if you want to say "Button1" to trigger setOnClickListener then add this line Button1.setOnClickListener(this); in onCreate method.

Comment: what view you are using to trigger setOnClickListener ? is it button or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to say "**Button1**" to trigger setOnClickListener then add this line `Button1.setOnClickListener(this);`

in onCreate method.

so that when the Button1 is clicked, it will trigger onClick method

Comment: welcome..it happens when we are in the middle of the big code and we forget the smallest things :)

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `View.OnClickListener` is not enough. You need to register the listener with `setOnClickListener()` for all views you want to receive click events from.